# How to connect particular sets of points with (poly)lines?

Tags: postgis, gps, point, line, geometry-conversion

I have a timestamped point-table representing GPS-tracked places of different cars. To distinguish the cars there is a car-id for every point. So, a simplified version is looking like that:

[image]

Now, I want to write a query for connecting the places of each car chronologically with lines so that the track of each car can be displayed. The table is sorted chronologically, so it can be worked with the id's instead of the timestamps.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use the [ST_MakeLine](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_MakeLine.html) function.  There is an example of almost exactly what you are trying to do (if I have understood you correctly) [here](http://www.bostongis.com/postgis_makeline.snippet)