# Geoserver Point-to-Line Aggregation possible?

Tags: geoserver, point, line, elasticsearch

I'm trying to use Geoserver to serve a WMS displaying lines instead of points, but without changing the underlying data structure. Currently I'm displaying the data as simple points, which works fine.

Is it possible to use geometry / rendering transformations to connect the points to lines based on the timestamp?
Or is there a plugin that would allow me to aggregate the points to lines? For example by creating a lineString from the point's coordinates.

Environment:

- Geoserver 2.11.0
- ElasticSearch 5.3.2
- ElasticGeo 2.11.1-RC1 (Plugin    that allows Geoserver to use
  ElasticSearch as Datastore)

Elasticsearch data type:

- lat / lon mapped as GEO_POINT
- timestamp mapped as Date string or UNIX-based

Answer (score 1):

This is not going to be possible using the rendering transformations or styling as the renderer only "sees" one feature at a time.

The most likely way to do this is to make an SQL view that creates lines based on the points and time stamps. I think this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41183/how-to-connect-particular-sets-of-points-with-polylines) should help. However I'm not familiar with the ElasticGeo plugin so I don't know if this will work for that.